# Django: get all distinct values from attribute in db

Tags: python, django

So I have a model "site" which has an attribute country.
I need an endpoint that fetches all countries
I have following filter in my view:

```
 countries = Site.objects.order_by().values("country").distinct()
```

This returns a queryset. What's the best way to return this data?
A serializer uses a model, right? But this is just a queryset of strings..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need a list of the country values, you could use `values_list`:

```
countries = list(Site.objects.values_list("country",flat=True).order_by("country").distinct())
```

`values_list` returns tuples which can be iterated over, the `flat=True` makes it return a queryset of single values (so you'll still need to convert it to a list for returning in a json response in your end point).

So your endpoint might end up something like (using DRF):

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class CountriesView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        sites = Site.objects.all()
        country_list = list(sites.values_list("country", flat=True).order_by("country").distinct())
        data = {"countries": country_list}
        return Response(data=data, status=200)
```

Comment: Is there a difference if you do Site.objects or Site.objects.all() here?

Comment: good catch! Looking at the docs, it seems like you don't need `all()`